# Unable to verify contract on Etherscan Rinkeby Testnet

Tags: etherscan, verify

I am unable to verify the smart contract on Rinkeby testnet. I have deployed the code through truffle and developed using open-zeppelin. I have tried to look for solutions on this platform and I tried various ways mentioned but it is not helping me out.

I used oracles-combines-solidity to flatten the sol file and pasted the code in etherscan's solidity code but everytime I get the message below. Please help.

[image: rinkeby etherscan verify contract]

Edit: 
Following are the details:

TCRToken:0xf1608c8aead4d4feae7afe9dd9c657d27349d615, 
TCRSale:0x3bd1d8004fbd68b085d9b582729b9ad22698c813

Rinkeby URL:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0xf1608c8aead4d4feae7afe9dd9c657d27349d615

Source: https://github.com/parth5049/transboundary-credit-rating

Comment: Did you try what the tip suggests?

Comment: Does it work if you don't use the flattener?  (meaning if you cut and paste the contracts?)

Comment: @thefett how can I cut and paste around 10 contracts? Like I am using open-zeppelin and therefore my contract uses many other contracts like ERC20, StandardToken etc.

Comment: @smarx Yes I have tried various possible combinations. Optimizer On, Off, Runs: 0, 200 etc. I am sure that compiler version is right.

Comment: I doubt anyone will be able to help without being able to see the source code source code and the address of the contract.

Comment: @smarx I have edited the question and added the details.

Comment: I can't get `oracles-combine-solidity` to work for `TCRToken.sol`... it seems to not include the `ERC20` and `BasicToken` contracts.

Comment: I already have the flattened token file using oracles-combine-solidity. The challenge is I cannot verify using that code.

Comment: Well _I_ don't have the flattened source, so how am I supposed to help?

Comment: I managed to get the flattened source. For others following along, do an `npm install zeppelin-solidity` in the source repo; it appear to be a missing dependency. Also, `oracles-combine-solidity` gets confused by relative paths, so path an absolute path to the Solidity file being flattened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to verify source code for both of these contracts on Rinkeby:

- TCRToken: 0xf1608c8aead4d4feae7afe9dd9c657d27349d615
- TCRSale: 0x3bd1d8004fbd68b085d9b582729b9ad22698c813

I cloned https://github.com/parth5049/transboundary-credit-rating and did `npm install zeppelin-solidity`.

Then I cloned https://github.com/poanetwork/oracles-combine-solidity, did an `npm install`, and then ran `node index.js /full/path/to/transboundary-credit-rating/contracts/TCRToken.sol`. This produced `./out/TCRToken.sol`, which contained a properly flattened version of the source code.

I verified the source code using https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/verifyContract2, which supports the "run" option needed to verify contracts compiled with truffle. I used `0.4.18+commit.9cf6e910` as the compiler, optimizations enabled, and 200 runs.

Etherscan seemed to try to guess at the constructor parameters but got them wrong. `TCRToken` uses a single constructor parameter. ABI-encoded, it's `000000000000000000000000fdb0d9aca9f30d98d8bcbd54c596e764f6254fdc`.

I followed a similar procedure to verify `TCRSale`, but that time the constructor parameters were correctly filled in by Etherscan, so I didn't have to change anything.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess I was making the mistake of assuming the ABI-encoded parameter as it was generated by etherscan. Thank you again. I am now making some changes to the contract and will deploy soon.